# Where can I fetch Blink for JNI debugging?

Tags: debugging, java-native-interface

I want to debug both java and c codes in a single debugger. I found a paper written in 2009, the author of whom is now a group leader in IBM leading AI development.

https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/mckinley/papers/blink-oopsla-2009.pdf

The paper mentioned they have made a debugger named *Blink* which has good experience in JNI debugging.

The paper is written in 2009, and now is 2023. I also found many other places mentioned this product as an exist debugger, even in ppt.

But I haven't got any piece of its source code or binary, anyone got a knowledge?

I searched over the internet, got some articles mention that debugger. When I asked my coleague and teacher, they have no idea about that.

Comment: Is it a must to use the very same debugger? If not, you can easily configure IntelliJ tools to work quite effortlessly with `JNI` code: https://youtu.be/8Cjeq4l5COU?si=V8DPP7RHg_wxkEOE

Comment: The problem occured when our program running in an isolated environment, the server is reachable only using cli tool provided by cutom. So that in most cases we can only debug the project by logs, some guys told me that I can attach gdb onto running java process.

Comment: Take a look here. This is a complete `CLI` based solution for `JNI`: https://www.owsiak.org/jni-debugging-extreme-way/

Answer (score 0):

You missed this bit of the paper:

> The open-source release
> of Blink is available as part of the xtc package [9].
> [9] R. Grimm. xtc — eXTensible C. http://www.cs.nyu.edu/rgrimm/xtc/.